# Why is the character limit message trying to trick me?

Tags: bug, character-limit

I was writing an answer that exceeded the 30,000 character limit by a few hundred characters. I began trimming off characters until I got it to exactly 30,000 characters. But lo and behold, when I tried to post it I got an error message telling me that it is 185 characters above the limit:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Yet when I add a character and let the message update it tells me that there are only 30,001 characters:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

When I remove the added character the error message goes away. But as soon as I click "post" it comes right back saying that I'm over the limit by 185 characters.

If I leave the additional character (so that the message tells me that I am one character above the limit) and then click "post", it brings me back to the box and the number has somehow changed to 30,186:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

[image: Screenshot of error message]

One of these messages seems to be lying to me.

Comment: The delete key use are using is not really a delete key, but it inserts the characters `12345678912345678912345678912345678912345678912345678\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b` which has a length of `187` and just deletes the character (length of `1`) but takes up that many chars. `187 - 1` is `186`, which if you add `30000` gets you your new limit. No lying, just internal stuff that exisits for a reason. :)

Comment: The only question I have now is, what kind of weird Jewish furniture store sells a maimonidesk?

Comment: @Ethan K: That ought to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @EthanK I'm not sure I fully understand that, but in any case it adds 185 characters even without me deleting anything. As you can see from the final two screenshots the 185 characters got added merely from clicking "post" even without deleting anything.

Comment: @Alex It was a joke. It is the same as `\b` (a backspace) but takes up `187` characters.

Comment: [[exhibit a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98390/16706)]

Comment: Can you post your raw body of your post somewhere, so we can check it to see the cause?

Comment: @Ferrybig I can’t post it here as it would exceed the character limit. But Dr. Shmuel linked it in his comment above.

Comment: IIRC, I've seen that behavior when commenting.

Comment: @MikeWaters Regarding the comment character limit? I've never had this problem for that.

Comment: Alex, in comments you need to add a space character to trigger a ***correct*** recalculation, adding non-space characters (in a comment, at least) simply continues to add to the incorrect value until a clear space (and new word is started). ---- Maybe it works the same way for posts (which should have been saved on the site where you were writing last, if you didn't make another post afterwards), so you can test if it works.